# ASP.NET MVC - How to obtain file from FileResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Short version:
I have a third-party MVC Extension that returns the FileResult. I would like to be able to process the file before returning it to the client. How can I do that?

If you're interested in boring details, read below:

I'm using Devexpress XtraReports for reporting purposes. The problem is that it's PDF Export is terrible, but RTF one works great. I would like to create action&result filter that would  trick DevExpress into generating rtf instead of pdf (done) and convert the rtf to pdf using some other third-party library. The only problem is that I need to obtain rtf file from FileResult and return my own FileResult with the converted content.

//EDIT:
The code right now looks as follows:

```
        public virtual ActionResult ReportExport(TParameters parameters)
        {
            return DevExpress.Web.Mvc.ReportViewerExtension.ExportTo(this.GetReport(parameters));    
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said you are using a third-party MVC extension that returns a `FileResult` and you want to access the file details that are wrapped inside the result.

If you see the `FileResult`, it is an abstract class and I just know there are three built-in implementations are available in MVC (I don't aware about others): `FileContentResult`, `FileStreamResult` and `FilePathResult`.

All these classes provide public properties to access the details of the file. For ex. the `FileContentResult` contains a public property called `FileContents` that returns the content of a file as a byte array.

The third-party extension can return any `FileResult` implementation of the built-in types or badly(if you can't access those type) their own types as well. You can check the returned `FileResult` instance's type and cast it accordingly to access the file details.

```
var fileResult = ... returned by the MVC extension

if(fileResult is FileContentResult)
{
   var fileContentResult = fileResult as FileContentResult;   
   var fileContent = fileContentResult.FileContents;
   // process the file
}
else if(fileResult is FileStreamResult)
{
   var fileStreamResult = fileResult as FileStreamResult;
   var fileStream = fileStreamResult .Stream;
   //...
}
else if(fileResult is FilePathResult) // this result only contains the path 
                                      // of the file name
{
  //...
}
```

If you want make the things reusable you can implement a custom file result that takes the `FileResult` returned by the extension in the constructor and override the `WriteFile` method.

Comment: I've checked the concrete type and it's unfortunately their own XtraReportsFileResult :(

Comment: I've also found out that it iheriths from FileStreamResult :D

Answer (score 3):

The FileResult probably writes the file contents to the response stream. You can use a standard ASP.NET response stream using a filter. See this ancient article for details:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043851/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120308-1.aspx

Alternatively you could create your own ActionResult that invokes the DevExpress FileResult using a custom HttpContext with a fake response stream, which is where you would do your conversion.

Comment: Using plain old Response filter is probably the only option right now. What I don't like about this solution is that I need to cache the whole response to make it work. Maybe I can find rtf to pdf converter that works on streams.. Anyway, thank you very much.